# Programmatically Change Admin Password in Magento

Tags: magento

I trying to change Magento admin password by,

```
Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('admin')->setPassword($password);
```

But this doesn't seem to be work.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to add `save()`.

```
Mage::getModel('admin/user')
     ->loadByUsername('admin')
     ->setPassword($password)
     ->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it via a Query here is the query to run:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

the resulting password would be **'password'**, qX is the salt you could use any 2 letter combo..

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('bL123456'), ':bL') WHERE username='admin';
```

would make the password **123456** ...

Comment: I tried using qX, but didn't worked for me. How do I know which salt value to use ? Is the salt value stored at some config file or ?

Comment: Salt can be any arbitrary value like ':ab' or whatever